# Pycharm remote debug issue: Couldn't apply path mapping to the remote file

Tags: pycharm

I was trying to use remote debug on my code, I set up the remote interpreter and it works, I set a breakpoint on a function and it stops there:

```
predictions = self.box_predictor(att_feats)
```

But when I was trying step into this function, Pycharm raises

```
Couldn't apply path mapping to the remote file
```

The full output is as the screen shot

[image]

I tried the suggested ways but not work, could someone help?

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue, See [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48387#focus=Comments-27-4849128.0-0)  but workaround is to add `venv` as project's content root.

File> Settings > Project >Project Structure> +Add Content Root

Use + button to add venv folder such as `\home\username\venv\project\lib\python3.8\site-packages`

Comment: I don't see how this could be a solution, the interface does not allow you to add remote folders...